# Naruto fanfic where all the Jinchūriki lose their tailed beasts and become gamers

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, naruto

It is a gamer fanfic where not just Naruto but all of the Jinchūriki lose their tailed beasts and, in exchange, become gamers. Yagura broke the genjutsu that Obito placed on him. Gaara lost his auto defence but got it back after pleading with the system. I read this in like 2015 on fanfiction.net.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you referring to the *The Gamer* system where people become aware of their stats, and can grind them?

Comment: https://m.fanfiction.net/community/Naruto-Gamer-Fanfiction/131538/ might be a place to start

Comment: wasnt there fuzzyboots and yes i do mean the gamer system

Comment: not an oc centric but where all the jinuriki are gamers all canon no mc oc kind of deal get it